# Error executing DDL " alter table student add constraint UK_fe0i52si7ybu0wjedj6motiim unique (email)" via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to start Spring Boot/ Spring Data JPA project with MySQL data base. But there is a problem with setting the unique constraint on the `email` field. 
My code:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import static  javax.persistence.GenerationType.SEQUENCE;

@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "student_sequence", sequenceName = "student_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "student_sequence")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TEXT", unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    public Student(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String email, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
     }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydatabase
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

I try to change `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and after this all work perfect, but I don't need `update`, I need `create-drop`. 
Also , I try to change `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` to `MySQL5Dialect`,`MySQL55Dialect` etc. But nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

what worked for me was removing **columnDefinition="TEXT"** from **@Column**

you should have this instead: `@Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)`

or

you can remove **unique=true** from **@Column** and add it manually with SQL

```
alter table student add constraint ~constraint_name~ unique(email(~length~)
```

*Example:*

```
alter table student add constraint student_unique_email unique(email(50))
```

Good Luck with The amigosCode course.

Answer (score 0):

remove `, unique = true`     from  `@Column(name = "email".....)}`

and add this
`uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name="student_email_unique",columnNames = {"email"})`
inside the `@Table` annotation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).